# Kafka logs configuration is not be picked up when starting kafka via Confluent CLI

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to upgrade from the apache kafka to the confluent kafka

As the storage of the temp folder is quite limited I have changed the log.dirs of server.properties to a custom folder

```
log.dirs=<custom  location>
```

Then try to start kafka server via the Confluent CLI (version 4.0) using below command :

```
bin/confluent start kafka
```

However when I check the kafka data folder, the data still persitted under the temp folder instead of the customzied one.

I have tried to start kafka server directly which is not using the Confluent CLI

```
bin/kafka-server-start etc/kafka/server.properties
```

then seen the config has been picked up properly

is this a bug with confluent CLI or it is supposed to be

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to upgrade from the apache kafka to the confluent kafka

There is no such thing as "confluent kafka".

---

You can refer to the Apache or Confluent Upgrade documentation steps for switching Kafka versions, but at the end of the day, both are *Apache Kafka*.

On a related note: You don't need Kafka from the Confluent site to run other parts of the Confluent Platform.

---

The `confluent` command, though, will read it's own embedded config files for running on localhost only, and is not intended to integrate with external brokers / zookeepers.

Therefore, `kafka-server-start` is the *production* way to run *Apache* Kafka

Answer (score 0):

Confluent CLI is meant to be used during development with Confluent Platform. Therefore, it currently gathers all the data and logs under a common location in order for a developer to be able to easily inspect (with `confluent log` or manually) and delete (with `confluent destroy` or manually) such data.

You are able to change this common location by setting

`export CONFLUENT_CURRENT=<top-level-logs-and-data-directory>`

and get which location is used any time with:

`confluent current`

The rest of the properties are used as set in the various `.properties` files for each service.